# Rails: method in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, instance

So, I tried searching (a lot :( ) and haven't been able to find anything to help.

I feel like this is something I've done before, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I have installed a gem (Recommendable, yay!), that allows me access to a bunch of methods(?):

> > user.like(movie)
> >     => true

In a view, I tried putting <%= link_to "Like", @user.like(@movie) %>... however, this seems to actually just run @user.like(@movie) on page load... automatically setting that user to like that movie.

What am I missing? :\

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you want to link to a certain url, where the corresponding controller handles the logic? Pseudo code -> `user_like_url(@user, @movie)` which resolves to `/someone/like/life-of-pi` for example?

Comment: You're missing the realization that Ruby/Rails code runs _on the server_, when the request is received and processed by the controller/action and the view is rendered. What I think you want is for code to execute (some behavior to happen) when the user clicks a link _on the browser_ (or client-side), like what @JustusRomijn said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a a LikesController for stuff like this I guess. And then you can remote link to the create action and inside this create action you can actually do the like you want to do:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # assuming you have some method to get you the current_user
    # and assuming you just want to like movies
    movie =  Movie.find_by_id(params[:id])
    current_user.like(movie) if movie  
    # maybe check for success and return some meaningfull message
  end
end
```

and then inside the view you can do:

```
<%= link_to "Like", likes_path(@movie), remote: true %>
```

This should trigger the like.

Don't forget to create a route in routes.rb for the LikesController.

You should always keep in mind, that for an action a user should be able to take, you need an action in a controller. The view always just presents a given state to the user with options to take action.